# Java - Create an invocation handler?

Tags: java, method-invocation, invocationhandler

I am trying to implement a factory class that generates objects and intercept all public methods.

I am trying to invoke 2 methods here. 1:the already invoked method 2: a method in my base.
Any idea how I can achieve this?

```
public class LoggerFactory {


    public LoggerFactory() {
    }

        // Clazz is always a class inheriting from Loggable
    public Object newInstance(Class clazz) {
        return Proxy.newProxyInstance(clazz.getClassLoader(), new Class[] {clazz}, handler);
    }

    private InvocationHandler handler = new InvocationHandler() {

        @Override
        public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
            // Call logStartingTime on object

            // Call invoked method on object

            // Call logEndingTime on object

            return null;
        }
    };
}
```

My Abstract class:

```
public abstract class Loggable {

       void logStartingTime() {
          log.info(“start time = ” + new Date());
          // also log some info about the state of the object
       }

       void logEndingTime() {
          log.info(“ending time = ” + new Date());
           // also log some info about the state of the object
       }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you could accomplish that with [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/).

Comment: +1. To be more specific, it doesn't make much sense to have `Loggable` as a base class. What if you had some other composable behavior you also wanted to include? AOP seems like a better approach.

Answer (score 2):

The [Proxy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) class only supports proxying interfaces, not classes.

[CGLib](http://cglib.sourceforge.net/) does have the ability to create proxies from classes and do what you need.  The [Beans example](http://cglib.sourceforge.net/xref/samples/Beans.html) may provide a good starting point.